# 500 Error after some time Azure app service hosted API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am getting 500 internal server error after some request / some time and it remains as is for all the request after that. To correct this thing I need to restart app service and it start working again. So each request to API throws *500 - Internal server error* continuously after some time.

As per my analysis from Advance Tool **Kudu**, I can see difference in request flow of **500 Internal server error** and **200 OK** is after **AspNetHttpHandlerLeave** it goes to **GENERAL_CHILD_REQUEST_START** in case of 200 ok; where as it never go to *GENERAL_CHILD_REQUEST_START* in case of 500 Internal server error.

Was not able to figure out what exact issue caused **AspNetHttpHandler** to throw exception?

Comment: Have you turned on the detailed error message in Diagnostics logs tab of Azure portal? If yes, please provide the detail error message for further discussion.

Comment: Diagnostic log not showing any details about this error; as the request throwing 500 Internal Server error from request pipeline itself. Please let me know what else details can help you to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you checked the memory usage when your web app is not useable? The issue maybe caused by memory leak. You could check the memory usage using Quotas or Metrics features provided by Azure portal.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-monitor

Comment: Memory Usage in 0% when it happen's, App heath is green always, Availability is 100%.Still all request are failing with 500 Error. Looked again for the diagnostic logs - no log's available as request is not actually passing through HTTPHandler. Still at the same position not even able to figure out what must be causing the issue. Your help is appreciated. Please let me know if you have any idea?

Comment: I got the issue here. Have added exception filer to log all un-handled exception as there was exception being thrown from constructor it was getting out from request pipeline